# Using explicit casting to solve invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘AVRounding’

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg, libav

I'm trying to follow the "learn ffmpeg the hard way" guide on github (https://github.com/leandromoreira/ffmpeg-libav-tutorial#chapter-2---remuxing) and when I try to run the remuxing code for myself using a C++ compiler I always get the error

```
invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘AVRounding’[-fpermissive]
```

The only real difference between my code and the github original is that I take the input filename and output filename as parameters instead. Doing some resarch I have found that AVRounding is a enum? I think? Thus I need to explicitly cast somehow. However I'm failing to understand how explicit casting works and how I would use it to solve my issue. Where would I cast it?
Here's the line that causes the issue:

```
packet.pts =  av_rescale_q_rnd(packet.pts, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base, AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF|AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX);
packet.dts =  av_rescale_q_rnd(packet.dts, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base, AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF|AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX);
```

Could anyone explain how to solve the issue? Sorry if it's a beginners mistake. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`AVRounding`](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.3/group__lavu__math.html#ga921d656eaf2c4d6800a734a13af021d0) is indeed an enum (to be exact, an *unscoped* enum without a fixed underlying type):

```cpp
/**
 * Rounding methods.
 */
enum AVRounding {
    AV_ROUND_ZERO     = 0, ///< Round toward zero.
    AV_ROUND_INF      = 1, ///< Round away from zero.
    AV_ROUND_DOWN     = 2, ///< Round toward -infinity.
    AV_ROUND_UP       = 3, ///< Round toward +infinity.
    AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF = 5, ///< Round to nearest and halfway cases away from zero.
    /**
     * Flag telling rescaling functions to pass `INT64_MIN`/`MAX` through
     * unchanged, avoiding special cases for #AV_NOPTS_VALUE.
     *
     * Unlike other values of the enumeration AVRounding, this value is a
     * bitmask that must be used in conjunction with another value of the
     * enumeration through a bitwise OR, in order to set behavior for normal
     * cases.
     *
     * @code{.c}
     * av_rescale_rnd(3, 1, 2, AV_ROUND_UP | AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX);
     * // Rescaling 3:
     * //     Calculating 3 * 1 / 2
     * //     3 / 2 is rounded up to 2
     * //     => 2
     *
     * av_rescale_rnd(AV_NOPTS_VALUE, 1, 2, AV_ROUND_UP | AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX);
     * // Rescaling AV_NOPTS_VALUE:
     * //     AV_NOPTS_VALUE == INT64_MIN
     * //     AV_NOPTS_VALUE is passed through
     * //     => AV_NOPTS_VALUE
     * @endcode
     */
    AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX = 8192,
};
```

The values you are trying to pass to `av_rescale_q_rnd()` are not themselves `int`s, but they are *implicitly* convertible to `int`.  However, C++ does not allow an `int` to be *implicitly* converted to a `enum`, and FFmpeg does not define an `operator|` for `AVRounding` in C++, so the result of OR'ing the values of `AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF` and `AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX` together actually does produce an `int`, hence the need for a type-cast to go back to an `AVRounding`, eg:

```cpp
packet.pts =  av_rescale_q_rnd(..., static_cast<AVRounding>(AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF|AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX));
packet.dts =  av_rescale_q_rnd(..., static_cast<AVRounding>(AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF|AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX));
```

You can manually define an `operator|` to avoid that type-casting at the call site, if you wish, eg:

```cpp
inline AVRounding operator|(AVRounding a, AVRounding b)
{
    return static_cast<AVRounding>(static_cast<int>(a) | static_cast<int>(b));
}

...

packet.pts =  av_rescale_q_rnd(..., AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF|AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX);
packet.dts =  av_rescale_q_rnd(..., AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF|AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX);
```